# target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.watchkit2-extension', but there's no such product type for the 'iphonesimulator' platform

Tags: ios

this error pops up when I try to run my project

target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.watchkit2-extension', but there's no such product type for the 'iphonesimulator' platform

I don't know what to do please help.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, most of the things were ok when I add watchkit extension with xcode 7. but debug target of the extension was iOS. So when I run in debug/simulator I got this error. I have to change them to WatchOS. and Solved. 
Select `Project > Targets > Supported Platform > Debug > watchOS` (I had iOS here).

[image]

Comment: Hi karim! Where can I find "Project" item to select? You nicely described the "Supported Platforms" section, but I cannot find it anywhere. Thanks in advance!

Comment: in build settings

Comment: @DJGruby Please make sure 'all' in build settings sub menu.

Answer (score 4):

Select watch targets,Then change tab to Build settings (Please make sure you selected all build settings, marked in screenshot). Then change supported platforms to WatchOS. and Solved.

[image: marked in screenshot]

Comment: Not working for me!