# RealmSwift-1.2 and iOS-9 with iOS-based WatchKit-Extension (all on iPhone)

Tags: swift, watchkit, realm

Using iOS-9.01 / Swift-1.2 / RealmSwift-1.2 / XCode-7.0.1:

I try to update my working AppleWatch-1.0 App to iOS9, still working with Swift-1.2 and STILL WANT TO HAVE THE AppleWatch-App RUN ON THE IPHONE (not natively on the AppleWatch).

When first opened in XCode7, the App unfortunately does no longer compile ! I end up with the following error:

Error message (1) after first startup in XCode7 (app worked fine under XCode6.4):

```
Target 'Pods-MyApp WatchKit Extension' of project 'Pods' was rejected as an
implicit dependency for 'Pods_MyApp_WatchKit_Extension.framework' because it
doesn't contain platform 'watchsimulator' in its SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS 'iphonesimulator,
iphoneos'
```

What does that error mean ???

I read [in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31632660/target-specifies-product-type-com-apple-product-type-watchkit2-extension-but), that the Architecture-Settings (i.e. debug-target) of the WatchKit-Extension need to be set differently

What does the Base-SDK (under Build Settings/Architecture) setting need to be ???

After first startup, the Base-SDK is by default set to watchOS (as seen in first picture below). But since I would like TO KEEP THE APP A PURELY iPhone-App, I assume, this Base-SDK should rather be set as "Latest iOS (iOS 9.0)". Is this correct ??

[image]

After setting the Base-SDK to "Latest iOS (iOS 9.0)", the "General" tab dissappears(see picture below). So I assume this is not correct either ?? Or is it ?

[image]

Not only the "General" tab dissappears, but moreover another error crops up:

Error message (2) after changing Base-SDK to Latest-iOS (iOS 9.0):

```
target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.watchkit2-extension',
but there's no such product type for the 'iphonesimulator' platform
```

If set the "Supported Platform" for the Debug and the Release differently ([according to the suggestion of the other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31632660/target-specifies-product-type-com-apple-product-type-watchkit2-extension-but)), I am back to Error-message1

See picture below for the mixture of Supported Platform settings:

[image]

Error message (1) is now back....

```
Target 'Pods-MyApp WatchKit Extension' of project 'Pods' was rejected as an
implicit dependency for 'Pods_MyApp_WatchKit_Extension.framework' because it
doesn't contain platform 'watchsimulator' in its SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS 'iphonesimulator,
iphoneos'
```

The question remains: What else is there to do in order to make the App work as desired ??
Any help on this is appreciated !

Additionally, my Cocoa Podfile looks as follows:

```
xcodeproj 'MyApp.xcodeproj'
workspace 'MyApp.xcworkspace'
platform :ios, '9.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!

source 'https://github.com/artsy/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

use_frameworks!
link_with 'MyApp', 'MyApp WatchKit Extension'

def shared_pods
      pod 'Realm', :git => 'https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git', :branch => 'swift-1.2'
      pod 'RealmSwift', :git => 'https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git', :branch => 'swift-1.2'
end

target 'MyApp' do
    shared_pods
end

target 'MyAppTests' do
    shared_pods
end

target 'MyApp WatchKit Extension' do
    platform :ios, '9.0'
    shared_pods
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the Swift 1.2 version of Realms. iOS 9 uses Swift 2.0, so I believe you just need to use the most up-to-date version of Realms:

```
def shared_pods
      pod 'Realm'
      pod 'RealmSwift'
end
```

Comment: Hi Charles, this looks like a solution, thank you. The question remains: Is it also possible to use RealmSwift with the Swift-1.2 branch plus iOS9 with Swift-1.2 (i.e. before doing the auto-update to Swift 2.0) ??? What I've found out - one should not change to WatchOS2 (i.e. when first launching XCode7 with iOS9, the user has to un-tag WatchOS2...)....

Comment: You should always use the latest versions of developer tools. I don't think there's a way to strictly use Swift 1.2 with iOS 9, but you can always use #avalible to target iOS versions with code.