# Cordova's build of xcode fails due to inability to find watchkit2-extension in iphonesimulator platform

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I've updated a watchkit product in Xcode to WatchOS 2 but now Cordova CLI won't compile the code - or, more specifically, the xcodebuild command it executes fails. Error message:

> Check dependencies target specifies product type
>   'com.apple.product-type.watchkit2-extension', but there's no such
>   product type for the 'iphonesimulator' platform
>
> ** BUILD FAILED **

My Cordova, Cordova ios platform, and Xcode are all up to date.

I followed the [advice elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31632660/target-specifies-product-type-com-apple-product-type-watchkit2-extension-but) of ensuring both watchkit and watchkit extension in Xcode are set to:

Select Project > Targets > Supported Platform > Debug > watchOS

I tried adding a device and simulator using these commands:

```
xcodebuild -workspace I-Ching.xcworkspace -scheme watchkitapp build
xcodebuild -workspace I-Ching.xcworkspace -scheme watchkitapp -destination 'name=iphonesimulator' build
```

But the Cordova compile still fails.

What Cordova is running is this command:

> xcodebuild with args:
>   -xcconfig,/Users/gpiuser/Sites/i-ching/net.brian-fitzgerald.changes/net.brian-fitzgerald.changes/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,I-Ching.xcworkspace,-scheme,I-Ching,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,-destination,platform=iOS
>   Simulator,name=iPhone
>   SE,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/gpiuser/Sites/i-ching/net.brian-fitzgerald.changes/net.brian-fitzgerald.changes/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/gpiuser/Sites/i-ching/net.brian-fitzgerald.changes/net.brian-fitzgerald.changes/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch

Is there a way for me to edit the xcodebuild arguments Cordova issues? I read elsewhere that all I need do is remove that -sdk and I'm golden. The documentation mentions using a build.json file to modify xcodebuild settings, but yipes, is that really the answer? (and where does that json file need to go to get read on compile?)

I can compile the code successfully in Xcode, so in theory I don't need Cordova's xcodebuild to run at all. But I fear Cordova's refusal to compile is a symptom of something deeper that's going to eventually bite me in the butt: I've lost my Watchkit code twice now either to updates to Xcode or to the ios platform in Cordova -- the watchkit and watchkit extension directories simply vanish from Xcode, though they remain intact on the drive. I really don't want to lose that code and rebuild it again from backups -- it's excruciatingly fiddly. Any advice?

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: Negative. When I compile with "cordova build ios" it still throws the error.  I can then successfully run and build in Xcode, but I've given up on ever seeing "Build Succeeded" on the terminal command line again.